# How to add Click-to-Call feature in html where phone number is pulled from a dynamic text box?

Tags: html, crm, voip

I'm looking to see if it is possible to add a click to call feature on a website used by the company I work for. The link would take the phone number from a CRM and dial using a VOIP. The CRM used is Lead Perfection and the VOIP is Five9. This isn't anything required by my job or "strictly necessary" as callers can just copy/paste the phone number, but I'd like to make things slightly more efficient. Unfortunately, I don't know anything really about html and I can only find information and guides online in cases where the phone number is the same every time.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<a href="tel:https://app-scl.five9.com/appsvcs/rs/svc/orgs/DomainID/interactions/click_to_dial?number=XXXXXXXXXXPhone&amp;campaignId=outbound=&amp;checkMultipleContacts=false&amp;skipDNCCheck=false">Click To Call</a>
```

I don't think it's this simple but don't know enough to actually figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Your description was somewhat convoluted, but from my understanding, you're trying to create a dynamic textbox that can change the phone number being called when a link is clicked.

The below code has a textbox where the number is inserted. Every time the value of the text box is changed, it will change the `href` attribute of the link below it, allowing the phone number to dynamically change. For the sake of user feedback, the `textContent` of the link is dynamically changed as well.

```js
document.getElementById("phone-num").addEventListener("input",function(e){
     document.getElementById("call-link").href = "tel:" + e.target.value;
     document.getElementById("call-link").textContent = "Call " + e.target.value;
});
```

```html
Number to Call: <input type="tel" id="phone-num">
<br><br>
<a href="tel:0" id="call-link">No number to call</a>
```

Comment: I think I have a better way to word this. Our CRM auto-populates a text box with a phone # when you click on a "lead" that pulls up all customer information. I just need to add a link next to that box to call whatever number is in it and I need to make sure that it calls using our VOIP, Five9. Here's what the html from the CRM looks like for the text box: '<input name="txtPhone" type="text" id="txtPhone" onkeydown="javascript:ShowSave();" onchange="javascript:ShowSave();" style="width:120px;">'